# When I create a SQL table in Workbench, a error occurs

Tags: mysql, workbench

[enter image description here][1]

Screenshot
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hiai9.jpg

Comment: A table must contain at least one column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how [CREATE TABLE](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-create-a-table-in-mysql) works.

I see you have a database, **new_schema**, already created.

You need to input column names and the details of the types of variables that will go in the columns.

For example, to create a **new_table** with three (3) columns:

```
    USE new_schema
```

then

```
    CREATE TABLE new_table (
                             new_column_1 VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
                             new_column_2 VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
                             new_column_ 3 INT NOT NULL,
                             PRIMARY KEY(new_column_1)
    );
```

I hope this helps.

Ps: rather than upload an image alone; it is best to share the code you used or are having difficulty with getting to work.